# Deploy custom branding to multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, branding

I have custom master pages, custom page layouts created on one of the o365 site. I want to package this and want to deploy it on my multiple o365 site collections. So that after deployment this branding should be available to deployed sites.